# 僕のプログラムは何が問題があります。（Fibonacci Sequence)

Tags: c

コードの初心者です。

Fibonacci　Sequence　を表すプログラムを書いて見ましたが、最初の４６項は正しいですが、どうしてか47項になると数字は正しくなくなる。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

僕のコード

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

47項になると値は０より低くなる。
原因はわかりません、僕は何が間違ってるのでしょうか？

Comment: コードを画像にして貼り付けるよりも、ソースコードのテキストを貼り付けるほうが良いです。
画像ファイルにしてしまうと回答者が手元でソースコードをビルドして動作を確認しようとした際にその作業が困難なものになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今度気をつけます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

47番目の数値が`int`であらわせる最大値を超えたのでオーバーフローして無効な数値になったためです。

そこまでで止めるか、もっと大きい値を扱える(コンパイラや環境に依存しますが)`long`や`long long`に変えるといった対処が考えられます。

[整数型（char型 int型）の最大値と最小値 - limits.h](https://webkaru.net/clang/limits-header/)

> int の最大値 = 2147483647
> long の最大値 = 9223372036854775807

[色々なデータ型の最大値、最小値](http://www1.cts.ne.jp/%7Eclab/hsample/IO/IO19.html)

> int の最大値: 32767
> long の最大値: 2147483647

[C と C++ 整数の制限](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=vs-2019)

> INT_MAX　　int 型変数の最大値。　　2147483647
> LONG_MAX　 long 型変数の最大値。　 2147483647
> LLONG_MAX　long long 型変数の最大値。　9,223,372,036,854,775,807

[１００番目までのフィボナッチ数列](http://www.suguru.jp/Fibonacci/Fib100.html)

> 47　2971215073